# MySQL: Get list of duplicate values between tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that have address data.  Here is a partial representation:

table 1 (main data):

```
id  address        city      state
1   1234 main st   seattle   wa
2   2345 oak st    portland  or
3   3456 maple st  boise     id
```

and table 2 (secondary data):

```
id  address         city         state    to_insert
1   4567 first st   sacramento   ca       1
2   5678 second st  phoenix      az       0
3   2345 oak st     portland     or       1
```

I need to first get a list of values from table 2 that are flagged as to_insert (bit) that already exist in table 1, so I can manually edit the data and insert them (so they're not duplicate).  How do I get a list of duplicates from table 2 (secondary data) that already exist in table 1 (main data)?

Comment: Are the addresses exactly the same? Or it may have some different characters (in that case it will be very difficult)

Comment: They are exactly the same

Comment: Use `insert ignore ... ` instead of plain `insert ...`

Comment: Even the IDs in both tables?

Comment: Jorge - no the IDs are different

Comment: Shadow - I want the list so that I can manipulate the data. Insert...ignore will insert the data and leave me with no results

Comment: You can get the matching records with a simple inner join on the fields you want to check.

Comment: Shadow - do you have an example?

Comment: Man, any basic sql tutorial will have an example for inner join.

Comment: Shadow - of course I know how to do an inner join, I was wondering if there was one with insert...ignore that would bring back the data without inserting anything

Comment: If you want a list of matching records between 2 tables, that's a simple select with inner join. Can you pls make up your mind what you are really looking for?

Comment: Shadow - I want to insert a set of duplicate data after manipulating it so that it is not duplicate.  Basically a select, then updates, then insert. The end result is that I want to insert the data

Comment: Well, your question does not reflect this, you need to update the question. You also need to provide some explanation as to what and how you would like to change the matching records because that will have a huge impact on the answer. If the changes can only be done manually, then you first have to update the matching records manually so they no longer match and then do the insert. You can also change the data in the matching fields in the select part of an insert ... select ... so that the inserted data will not be duplicates.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: After the edit it is a simple select with an inner join and a where criterion. Truly is that all?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't get me the information that I need

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) to get the duplicate rows on `table2`:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 t2 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table1
    WHERE t2.address = table1.address
        AND t2.city = table1.city
        AND t2.state = table1.state
);
```

**You can find a working example here:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/110b9a/1/0

To `INSERT` the data from `table2` to `table1` you can use the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (address, city, state) 
SELECT address, city, state FROM table2 
WHERE NOT id IN (
    SELECT t2.id FROM table2 t2 WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM table1
        WHERE t2.address = table1.address
            AND t2.city = table1.city
            AND t2.state = table1.state
    )
);
```

Comment: That will not work since the IDs may differ one from another.

Comment: Although the OP said that it is exactly the same... It may work. :)

Comment: Jorge, you are right - if I do it this way, it brings back a list of addresses that aren't all duplicates (the actual addresses don't exist in table 1). The IDs are different between the tables but the actual address data is the same

Answer (score 1):

You could use an insert select with not in subselect

```
insert into table1 (address , city , state)
select address, city,  state
from table2 
where  (address , city , state) not  in (select address, city,  state from table1)
```

Comment: You may be missing `in` after `not`. However, if this is truly the answer, then this topic is a duplicate and should be closed down as such.

Answer (score 1):

if you want those values which are not duplicate

```
insert into  table1 select * from table2 where 
row(id,address,city,state) not in (select * from table1);
```

if you want those values which are duplicate

```
insert into table1 select * from table2 where 
row(id,address,city,state) in (select * from table1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a SELECT with a GROUP BY clause. Let's say name is the column you want to find duplicates in:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) c FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING c > 1;
```

This will return a result with the name value in the first column, and a count of how many times that value appears in the second.

Comment: The duplicates are not within a single table. Pls read the question again.